# Is there a tool to monitor activity on mount point or directory?

Tags: centos, samba, monitoring, automounting, cifs

I'm trying to find out why automount timeout does not kick in and need to detect any system activity that access a specific catalog or subtree, e.g the cifs mount point.

My suspicion is that some cron/systemd daemon parse all mounted file systems (both local and networked) more frequently than the 300 second autofs timeout as shortening it to 10 seconds works as expected.

This is on CentOS8.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but the inotify api does not give the info I need to identify which process triggers the event. From the man page:  The  inotify  API  provides  no information about the user or process that triggered the inotify event.

Comment: Using fatrace is the closest I've come so far.